# Stuck in infinite loop after comparing two strings

Tags: c++

I have created a function that compares a string that the user inputs against a string inside of a struct array that was originally pulled from a file.

The list of strings that I am testing against are "Austin, Dallas, Washington D.C., and Chicago". Every city works except for Washington D.C. which throws the program into an infinite loop. I have tried debugging and rewriting parts of the code but the same thing keeps occurring.

The text file being read

```
Austin,Houston,109,140
Washington D.C.,Seattle,139,421
Austin,New York,94,1511
Dallas,Austin,93,74
Chicago,Las Vegas,149,1039
```

the first city is the departing city. The second city is the arrival city. Then the first number is the cost of the flight with the second number being the distance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct data {
    string departureCity;
    string arrivalCity;
    int cost;
    int distance;
};

void readFlights(data flightList[], int& SIZE) {
    ifstream inData("flights.csv"); // Opens csv file
    string flightCost;
    string flightDistance;
    int i = 0;
    // Goes through the csv file and assigns each string and int into a struct array
    // Having issues where it reads an additional line even though it should read eof
    while (!inData.eof()) {
        getline(inData, flightList[i].departureCity, ',');
        getline(inData, flightList[i].arrivalCity, ',');
        getline(inData, flightCost, ',');
        flightList[i].cost = stoi(flightCost);
        getline(inData, flightDistance);
        flightList[i].distance = stoi(flightDistance);
        i++;
    }
    inData.close(); // Closes csv file
    SIZE = i-1;
}

void printFlightsFrom(data flightList[], int SIZE) {
    string userInput;
    int i = 0; //array counter
    bool cityCheck = false; //Checks to see if the users city was used.
    cout << "Enter a city you are looking to depart from." << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;

    do {
        if (!userInput.compare(flightList[i].departureCity)) {
            cout << "Departure City: " << flightList[i].departureCity
                 << " Arrival City: " << flightList[i].arrivalCity
                 << " Cost: " << flightList[i].cost
                 << " Distance: " << flightList[i].distance << endl;
            cityCheck = true;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < 5);

    if (cityCheck == false) {
        cout << "You have entered an unavailable city. Returning to main menu." << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int SIZE = 100;
    data flightList[SIZE]; //Creates an array of size 100 for storing the file data
    readFlights(flightList, SIZE); //function that opens a file and writes the contents to a struc array

    int menu_choice = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Select an action:" << endl;
        cout << "2) Show the flights that depart from a given city" << endl;
        cout << "4) Exit the program" << endl;
        cin >> menu_choice;

        switch (menu_choice) {
            case 2: printFlightsFrom(flightList, SIZE);
                    break;
            case 4: cout << "goodbye!" << endl;
                    break;
            default: cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
        }
    }while (menu_choice != 4);

    return 0;
}
```

When going through debugging, "Washington D.C." is never recognized as a city so the program backs out back to main and keeps going through the switch for menu_choice. It never asks for user input again and keeps pumping out the cout lines in main.

Any help is greatly appreciated

UPDATE: While the string "Washington D.C." still wont compare properly, I have narrowed the infinite loop issue down to the do while loop. After I type characters into the menu_choice variable, it says invalid choice and then never gives the user a chance to input a new menu_choice. It types everything out again and then of course its an "invalid choice" then continues the loop indefinitely.

Comment: I assume the problem is the space in the input, can you try WashingtonD.C.

Comment: WashingtonD.C. triggers the invalid input response.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's not recognizing "Washington D.C." when you enter it (perhaps the space?) I'd also guess that if you enter a name not in the list, it also fails. At the very least, you have 4 items (0-3) but you are searching 5 so the behavior will be unpredictable.

Comment: Style hint: You can put a break in place of the cityCheck=true that will break out of the while loop. Then checking i for being < the limit will tell you whether or not it was found. Also, full caps tend to be used for constants (#define).

Comment: I forgot to put that back to SIZE. In the readFlights function I have it write the list to an array and keep track of the array size, being the reason i wrote 5. I am starting to lose my mind ive been working on this issue so long.

Comment: Debugging hint: In the loop, print out exactly what is being compared, probably surrounded by square brackets to indicate any leading/trailing spaces and see what is being compared when it crashes.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure that `readFlights` does its job correctly? If not, can we see that code?

Comment: I have added in the readFlights code. Also, I will trying what you are talking about, Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >> userInput` actually reads up to space, hence it reads just "Washington", letting "D.C." into the input buffer.

Later, `cin >> menu_choice` pretends a number, but there is still "D.C." in the buffer, hence cin is set to "invalid". From then on, every read fails.

- If you need to read a string that is also supposed to contain spaces, use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) like `std::getline(std::cin, userInput)`.
- When attempting to read a number, check for failure (a user may enter whatever thing ...)

A way to check for invalid read is something like

```
while(!(cin>>menu_choiche))
{
    cout << "invalid choiche - retry\n";
    cin.clear(); cin.ignore(0u-1,'\n');
}
```

`cin >> menu_choice` returns `cin`, that convert to `false` if invalid. Hence the loop is executed on failure.  It clears the invalid state and discard anything up to a new line (thus throwing away whatever bad data).